# nativ query (java) vs view in DB - performance

Tags: java, sql-server, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

i'm using some native query (in java hibernate) which selects data from some tables.

my idea is to use views (MS SQL) instead of native query.

Can someone explain to me which is more performant ... are there any big differents?

thanks & best regards

Comment: That depends entirely on what queries are generated in java hibernate vs. view. But usually native queries allows to extract maximum performance if you know how to write good sql